# RedHat Perl 5.10.1-Getting error 'symbol lookup error:auto/Math/Pari/Pari.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr'

Tags: linux, perl

Need help with Perl version 5.10.1 on RedHat Linux 6.0.
I have searched related topics on StackOverflow but this does not relate to common "Symbol lookup error"

I am trying to run a perl script returns

> /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error: ./../lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/Math/Pari/Pari.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr.

and

> ./../lib/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/IO/Tty/Tty.so: undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr

I have tried:

1. updated IO module from CPAN to latest IO-1.25
2. yum update: to get system up-to-date.
3. updated Math-Pari-2.010808 from CPAN
4. updated Tty from CPAN

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256633/how-can-you-determine-what-perl-module-is-causing-undefined-symbol-perl-tstack

Answer (score 0):

See this previously asked question: [How can you determine what Perl module is causing "undefined symbol: Perl_Tstack_sp_ptr?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256633/how-can-you-determine-what-perl-module-is-causing-undefined-symbol-perl-tstack)

Also see this thread on perlmonks: [Symbol lookup error](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=832773)

Quoting from thread on perlmonks:

> Major Perl versions (5.6, 5.8, 5.10, 5.12) aren't binary compatible
>   with each other. You can't use a module with a compiled component if
>   you're using a different major version of Perl than the one that was
>   used to install the module. (I think you can also have problems if you
>   use an earlier minor version of Perl than the one with which the
>   module was installed.)